# How does SalesLineOpenOrder in Axapta get the itemId passed as an argument when invoked from the Inventory MAnagement>itemMaster>inquiries

Tags: axapta, x++

I want to understand how the form SalesLineOpenOrder when opened from the Inventory Management>item-Master>inquiries gets the itemid passed to it.
I have an issue where the form never successfully opens and freezes the application when invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These forms linked by dynalink.

The term dynalink refers to two data sources that are dynamically linked. If two data sources have a dynalink, when a record changes in the parent data source, the child data source is notified about that change. The query for the child data source is reexecuted to retrieve the appropriate related data.

Inter-form dynalinks occur between related data sources on forms where one form (InventTable) opens another form (SalesLineOpenOrder).